# Paginating and getting prices from a site using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I started to look at Scrapy and want to have one spider to get some prices of MTG Cards.

First I don't know if I'm 100% correct to use the link that select all the cards available in the beginning of the function:

```
name = 'bazarmtgbot'
allowed_domains = ['www.bazardebagda.com.br']
start_urls = ['https://bazardebagda.com.br/?view=ecom/itens&tcg=1&txt_estoque=1&txt_limit=160&txt_order=1&txt_extras=all&page=1']
```

1 - Should I use this kind of start_urls?

2 - Then, if you access the site, I could not find how to get the unit and price of the card, they are blank DIV's...

I got the name using:

```
titles = response.css(".itemNameP.ellipsis::text").extract()
```

3 - I couldn't find how can I do the pagination of this site to get the next set of items unit/prices. Do I need to copy the start_urls N times?

Answer (score 1):

1. (and 3) That would be fine to start on a given page. When scraping you can queue additional URLs to scrape by looking for something like the "next page" button, scraping that link, and `yield`'ing a `scrapy.Request` that you want to follow-up on. See [this part](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) of the Scrapy tutorial
2. That site may be using a bunch of techniques to thwart price scraping: the blank price divs are loading an image like the below and chopping parts of it up with gibberish CSS class names to form the number. You may need to do some OCR or find an alternative method. Bear in mind that because they're going to that degree, there might be other anti-scraping countermeasures.

[image: gibberish number map]

Comment: Got your point, tried to do some OCR and was going insane, hehe. To "bypass" this problem, I think that I thought in another way to do the work:
Using this URL:

https://bazardebagda.com.br/?view=ecom/item&tcg=1&card=6

I can scrap all the info I need... the question is, there is a way to tell to Scrappy to use wildcard instead of card=6, then I can pass all the numbers I want in this wildcard?